# What is the pythonic way to write my decorator?

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators, python-logging

My objective is to raise SystemExit and log the error when my program encounter an unexpected behavior.

I was doing something like:

```
logger.error('Unexpected behaviour')
raise SystemExit
```

In order to avoid the repetition in my code i tried to write a decorator to raise SystemExit at each logger.error call:

```py
error = logger.error
def error_from_logger(msg) :
    ''' Decorator for logger.error to kill the program at the call '''

    error(msg)
    raise SystemExit

logger.error = error_from_logger
del(error_from_logger)
```

So my question is: Is my decorator pythonic? And if not what is the best pythonic way to write it? (I saw people use @something but I don't understand it's usage).

Thanks!

Comment: This looks more like [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch)

Comment: @bracco23 Indeed... So it's not a decorator because it modify the behaviour of the function?

Comment: It's not a decorator because you're actually changing the `error` function of the `logger` module with a custom one you wrote, which actually adds behavior to the original one. It's a tricky move to have, it might not behave like you want, especially since you are having it throw an exception. I would go for a Facade pattern, using a custom object that in turns uses a logger instead.

Comment: @bracco23 Okay, you're right, I will do a separate object instead of modifying the logger one. Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been mentioned in the comments, what you have done isn't quite decorating.  This would be decorating:

```python
def call_then_exit(func):
    def called_and_exited(*args, **kwargs):
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        raise SystemExit
    return called_and_exited

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.error = call_then_exit(logger.error)  # this is the decoration

logger.error("some error has happened")  # prints the message and exists
```

@decorator is just syntactic sugar which you use when declaring a function.  This isn't much use to you if you are using a function/method declared elsewhere.

```python
@call_then_exit  # this is the decoration
def say_hi():
    print('hello')

say_hi()  # prints 'hi' and exits
print('did we exit?')  # we never reach this
```

> Is my decorator pythonic?

Arguably it is not because patching is ugly and it adds unexpected behaviour.  To be more explicit, you could make a `log_error_and_exit()` function or register your own logging class with `logging.setLoggerClass(OurLogger)` and maybe add a `.fatal_error()` method.  However, I think your solution is OK as-is.